# Angular Material: How to close MatSidenav from inside a method in the component instead of from the html?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

Using Angular + Angular Material 12

If you want to close the MatSidenav, then almost every solution I have found says to:
`(click)="sidenav.close()"` in the html component.

But I need that (click) for my logout function `(click)="onLogoutSideNav()"`

```
onLogoutSideNav() {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
```

I need to close MatSidenav from inside a method in the component instead of from the html. The only solution I could find says to:

```
sidenav!: MatSidenav
...
onLogoutSideNav() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.sidenav.close();
  }
```

But doing so returns undefined for this.sidenav.

There are a ton of solutions to use @ViewChild, but I haven't split my navs into header and sidebar components. I'm keeping it simple, doing so from within the app.component.

```
<mat-list-item *ngIf="isAuth" routerLink="/"><button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>logout</mat-icon><span class="sidenav-span" (click)="onLogoutSideNav()">Logout</span></button></mat-list-item>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call multiple functions on click event.
eg =>

```
(click)="onLogoutSideNav();test()"
```

hope this answers your question.

Comment: That did the trick.
(click)="onLogoutSideNav(); sidenav.close()" to be precise.
I didn't know you could call two things at once with a (click) just by separating them by a semi-colon.